# VB2012 register form with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Im trying to learn to register using VB program with MYSQL.

Im new to this, recently know how to connect to mysql and register.

The problem right now is that... I modified the code too much and I can not register anymore.

AND

I want to do the following:

1.only one unique user name can be register （display error when the same user name is entered)
-------2. username length > 5, password length >6-----3. Display register complete

Im just... lost somewhere... need a lot of help . Thank you.

```
Private Sub btnReg_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReg.Click
    Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim myData As MySqlDataReader
    Dim add As String
    Dim connect As MySqlConnection
    connect = New MySqlConnection()

    connect.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=jackie588727;password=jackie1218;database=root"



    Dim usercheck As String = "SELECT Username FROM User WHERE Username = '" + txtUser.Text + "'"
    Try
        connect.Open()
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MsgBox("Error connecting to database. Check your internet connection.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try



    myCommand.Connection = connect
    myCommand.CommandText = usercheck
    myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
    myData = myCommand.ExecuteReader


    If myData.HasRows = 0 Then
        add = "INSERT INTO user (Username, Password) VALUES('" + txtUser.Text + "','" + txtPass.Text + "')"
    Else
        MsgBox(txtUser.Text & " is being register, try again.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End If
    connect.Close()


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the line `If myData.HasRows = 0 Then`

as below

```
If not myData.HasRows Then
```

HasRows property will return true or false, if true then user already registered, you can show the message box, else you can insert.

Answer (score 0):

I think You should Try This:

```
    conn = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=jackie588727;password=jackie1218;database=root")
    Dim username As Boolean = True
    conn.Open()
    Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT * FROM TABLENAMEHERE WHERE Username = '" & TextBox1.Text & "';"
    Dim data As MySqlDataReader
    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim command As New MySqlCommand
    command.CommandText = sqlquery
    command.Connection = conn
    adapter.SelectCommand = command
    data = command.ExecuteReader
    While data.Read()
        If data.HasRows() = True Then
            MsgBox("Username Already in use!")
            username = False
            data.Close()
        Else
            data.Close()
            username = True
        End If
    End While
    data.Close()
    If username = True Then
        Dim sqlquery2 As String = "INSERT INTO NewTable (Username, Password, Wcoins)VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & "10" & "')"
        Dim data2 As MySqlDataReader
        Dim adapter2 As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim command2 As New MySqlCommand
        command2.CommandText = sqlquery2
        command2.Connection = conn
        adapter2.SelectCommand = command2
        data2 = command2.ExecuteReader
        MsgBox("You've Registered!")
        MsgBox("Welcome " + TextBox1.Text)
        My.Settings.Name = TextBox1.Text
        My.Settings.Save()
        Member.Show()
        Me.Close()
    End If
```

if something is wrong please correct me